# Speed up python response

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, serial-communication

I'm reading meter by self made code of python. Say I'm sending disconnect command with the following code:

```
import serial, crcmod, time
from decimal import *

serial_com_port = serial.Serial("COM11", 9600, timeout=5)

def remove_0x(data):
    newStr=''
    for x in data.split(' '):
        x=x[2:]
        if len(x)<2:
            x='0'+x
        newStr=newStr+x
    return(newStr)  

def remove_space(data):
    new_data = data.replace(" ", "")
    return new_data

def reformate(data):
    space = (" ".join([data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]))
    upper = space.upper()
    return upper

def crc_16(crc_16_input):
    _crc_func = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x11021, initCrc=0, xorOut=0xffff)
    output = bytearray.fromhex(crc_16_input)
    crc = _crc_func(output)
    output.append(crc & 0xff)
    output.append(((crc >> 8) & 0xffff))
    return output.hex()

def disconnect16():
    fix = ("A0032153")
    formated_fix = remove_space(fix)
    length = len(formated_fix) + 6
    actual_length = length/2
    dec = int(Decimal(actual_length))
    dectohex = hex(dec)
    final_length = remove_0x(dectohex)
    without_fcs = formated_fix[:2] + final_length + formated_fix[2:]
    fcs = crc_16(without_fcs)
    disconnect16 = "7E" + fcs + "7E"
    disconnect_request = bytearray.fromhex(disconnect16)
    startsend = time.time()
    serial_com_port.write(disconnect_request)
    endsend = time.time()
    print(f"Disconnect Command: {reformate(disconnect16)}")
    startre = time.time()
    disconnect_response = serial_com_port.read(255).hex()
    endre = time.time()
    print(f"Disconnect Response: {reformate(disconnect_response)}")
    print(endsend - startsend)
    print(endre - startre)

disconnect16()
```

now, result I got is:

```
Disconnect Command: 7E A0 07 03 21 53 03 C7 7E
Disconnect Response: 7E A0 07 21 03 1F 6B E9 7E
0.000988006591796875
5.0104076862335205
```

here's the catch. I want to reduce the response time of 5.01 seconds into some ms. because these 5 seconds delay is much longer, if I compare to C language code. If I use C language based script, this response time reduces to ms as it sends and received data in blink of an eye. so Is there any library or any other things I can make changes in my code to improve the response time?